# What should be done with edits made by unregistered users to their own posts?

Tags: discussion, review

I just came across this [edit suggestion review](https://history.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/27498). This is not the first time I have seen this unregistered user or some other similar user making drastic or overwhelming edits to apparently their own posts which almost always change the post completely e.g.:

1. [Edit 1](https://history.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/25635)
2. [Edit 2](https://history.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/25439)

Naturally I always reject them because I have no way of knowing if its the same person or someone else with the same name.

Yet given the persistence and writing style, I am almost sure its the same person but lacking any substantial evidence, I feel my hands are tied in this matter.

What should be done with huge edits proposed by an unregistered user to apparently his own previous posts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I asked a [similar question on meta.scifi](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6816/31936). The answers recommend rejecting a substantial edit with a custom reason linking the user to the [instructions on how to recover a lost account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/20528/299342). There is a [similar question and answer on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226649/299342).